# Prove that there exists $x$ such that $f(x) = f(x+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)= \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=a$,
> 2. $f(0) = b$, where $a < b$.
>
> > Prove that exists $x \in \mathbb R$ such that
> > $$ f(x) = f(x+1) $$

I've some intuition, because $b > a$ we have some $y \in \mathbb R$ that creates some sort of "hill" on the graph of the function $f(x)$, and if this "hill" has a width at least 1 then we can find some $x$ such that $f(x) = f(x+1)$, but what if every "hill" on the graph has a width smaller than 1? And how to formalize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, $f$ attains its maximum on $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, since it converges (or diverges) towards $a<b$ there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x)<b$ for all $x<-M$ and $x>M$. This allows to write
$$ \max_{\mathbb{R}} f = \max_{[-M; M]} f = f(x_\star) $$
for some $x_\star\in[-M; M]$ (see the [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)).

Now define on $\mathbb{R}$ the function $g\colon x\mapsto f(x)-f(x+1)$. Your question can be re-formulated as the existence of a zero for this function.
If $g(x_\star-1)=0$ or $g(x_\star)=0$ then we are done. Otherwise, $g(x_\star-1)<0$ and $g(x_\star)>0$. The [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) allows to conclude.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that only uses the intermediate value theorem.

Let $g(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$. The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n) = a-b < 0$ by telescoping sum. So there exists a positive integer $m_1$ such that $g(m_1) < 0$. Similarly, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(-n) = b-a > 0$, so there exists a negative integer $m_2$ such that $g(m_2) > 0$. Since $g$ is continuous, there is an $x\in (m_2,m_1)$ such that $g(x) = 0$.